# Function works for first 2 task but does nothing on the 3rd

Tags: excel, vba, function

This is an interesting one.

I have written a function that takes a list of data and separates the list into 2 worksheets. The first contains less than 90 days prior to invoice date and the 2nd contains greater than 90 days prior to invoice date. This function works as expected for the first and second list but for the 3rd list (same format as the other two) it fails to do anything.

The workbook has 7 pages.

Page 2 is the 1st list. Page 3 is the greater than 90 sheet for the 1st list.

Page 4 is the 2nd list. Page 5 is the greater than 90 sheet for the 2nd list.

Page 6 is the 3rd list. Page 7 is the greater than 90 sheet for the 3rd list.

For whatever reason the function works without fail until it is time to work page 6 and 7.

Here is my call to the function:

```
Call split90(2, first_of_month, inv_wb)
Call split90(4, first_of_month, inv_wb)
Call split90(6, first_of_month, inv_wb)
```

the 1st argument is used to define what page is being worked on. The 2nd argument is use to pass the first date for the month. The 3rd argument is used to pass the workbook where the function will be manipulating the list.

Here is the function:

```
Function split90(start_sheet, first_of_month, inv_wb)

    Dim rng_wk As Range
    Dim last_row As Integer
    Dim stop_row As Integer

    Debug.Print ("Before last_row: " & inv_wb.Worksheets(start_sheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    last_row = inv_wb.Worksheets(start_sheet).Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print ("After last_row: " & last_row)
    Set rng_wk = inv_wb.Worksheets(start_sheet).Range("C2:C" & last_row)

    For Each cell In rng_wk
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            If CDate(cell.Value) < CDate(first_of_month) - 90 And CDate(cell.Value) <> CDate("1/1/0001") Then
                stop_row = cell.Row
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next cell

    Set rng_wk = inv_wb.Worksheets(start_sheet).Range("A" & stop_row & ":H" & last_row)
    rng_wk.Cut Destination:=inv_wb.Worksheets(start_sheet + 1).Range("A2")

End Function
```

The above works as expected for list 1 and 2 but when I pass the number 6 for list 3 it just fails. Nothing. No error. Just nothing. All of my testing with `Debug.Print()` had shown me that for some reason `last_row` is not getting a value assigned to it when `start_sheet` is the integer `6`.

From the above `Debug.Print` I expect to see the last row of the list printed twice for each call to the function. Instead what I see is the last row printed twice for the first 2 list and only once for the 2nd list. It makes no sense to me.

Here are the results of the print.

```
Before last_row: 20892
After last_row: 20892
Before last_row: 3098
After last_row: 3098
Before last_row: 35738
```

As you can see for some reason the variable `last_row` is not getting assigned a value for the last group... But it is able to see the number before assigning to `last_row`.

Comment: Do you have an error handler in the code calling your function?  BTW it's best to avoid Integer and always use Long.

Comment: There are no errors. While debugging the macro just runs and then stops at the end. This macro is 300 lines long and everything works fine. Also if I just create 3 with statements it works fine as well.

Comment: An error is the only reason i can think of why you wouldn't see the last "After last row - now I'm noticing last row is >32000 which is above the Integer limit, so that *has* to be throwing an error.

Comment: It does not throw an an error. However if there is a limit I will take a look at using a long.

Comment: If that's not raising an error and you don't have "On Error Goto..." in your calling code then there's something wrong with your VBA environment.

Comment: @TimWilliams my VBA Environment is just the Microsoft VBA tool within Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim last_row As Integer
```

should be

```
Dim last_row As Long
```

The limit for Integer is ~32,000, so for large sets of data `last_row` will overflow and raise a run-time error.

Comment: In VBA Integer can have a value from -32,768 to 32,767: it can't hold a value of 35,738 and if you try to assign that value it will cause a run-time error 6 "Overflow".

Comment: Interesting. So After changing all my `Integer` variables to `Long` it fixed the problem. The odd thing is nothing else was affected by the `Integer` even though I works with rows greater than 32000 in other spreadsheets with this same MACRO. Regardless it is working now and I appreciate the help.